# JSON Parse errors in Logstash

Tags: logstash

When attempting to parse JSON data with Logstash, it seems to fail the parse and my JSON doesn't get sent to ES as expected.  Any suggestions would be great.  Attempting to log failed Wordpress logins, but having no luck with the parsing of the JSON.

Currently using Logstash 6.4.2 on FreeBSD 11.

Example log file.  File has nothing else but this data.

```
{
"username": "billy",
"password": "gfdgdfdfg4",
"time": "2019-02-03 00:39:11",
"agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/62.0",
"ip": "11.11.11.11"
}
```

Template

```
{
  "index_patterns": ["wpbadlogin*"],
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 0,
      "index.refresh_interval": "60s"
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "properties": {
          "host": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "password": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "agent": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
          }
        },
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Logstash config

```
input {

    file {
        type => "json"
        codec => "json"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        path => "/var/log/lighttpd/badlogin.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"#
        tags => ["wpbadlogin"]
    }
}

#filter { }

output {

    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }

    elasticsearch {

        hosts => ["10.0.5.30:9200"]
        template => "/usr/local/etc/logstash/templates/wpbadlogin.json"
        template_name => "wpbadlogin"
        template_overwrite => true
        index => "wpbadlogin"
    }
}
```

Error: https://pastebin.com/raw/KWEYGkLn

Comment: Logstash is line based. Your json document needs to be on a single line, else you will need process via the multiline codec first, and things will get messy.

Comment: DERP! That totally worked.  >_<